# Android 8 notification channel for a foreground service

Tags: android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo

I wonder if the following modification of my notification creation source is in accordance with Android 8.
*Before:*

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
// ... (some code omitted)
myNotification = builder.build();
// ... (some code omitted)
startForeground(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification);
```

*After:*

```
Notification.Builder builder;
if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 26 ) {
    builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
} else {
    final String ChannelId = "mypackage.NotificationChannelID";
    final CharSequence ChannelName = "My Notification";
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(ChannelId, ChannelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
    ((NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).
        createNotificationChannel(channel);
    builder = new Notification.Builder(this, ChannelId);
}
// ... (some code omitted)
myNotification = builder.build();
// ... (some code omitted)
startForeground(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification);
```

Especially, there remain at least two questions:

(1) I wonder if and where to add `void deleteNotificationChannel(String channelId)` to not produce any memory leak?

(2) Should I add `builder.setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)` and if yes why?

Comment: Regarding (1), why would you need to delete the channel?

Comment: If I stop the background service and start it again I wonder if the NotificationChannel is reused if `new NotificationChannel()` is called again. So, `deleteNotificationChannel()` may avoid a memory leak?

Comment: A `NotificationChannel` object is only used for the `createNotificationChannel()` call and the resulting IPC back to a system process to set up this channel. You don't need the `NotificationChannel` object anymore after that call. Moreover, you should only call `createNotificationChannel()` once per channel, unless you are changing its configuration (and there's very little that you can change once you create it). Hence, most of the time, you should not even *have* a `NotificationChannel` object.

Comment: Thanks, so then the above code modification is ok?

Comment: I would look to call `createNotificationChannel()` once for the life of your app, rather than once per notification. For example, you could [call `getNotificationChannel()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#getNotificationChannel(java.lang.String)) to see if the channel already exists. Otherwise, off the cuff, what you have seems fine. I don't know what the expectation is regarding `setCategory()`, though.

Comment: The expectation is: Does it help Android doing something better, then when being forced to guess